# Is it possible to specify sourcePath for AWS ECS in yml?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, amazon-ecs

I have docker-compose file, which I'm trying to upload to AWS ECS. I'm using `ecs-cli` to upload it. I run `ecs-cli compose up`, and everything works fine, except that I can not define `host.sourcePath` for docker named volumes. I want to do it in `ecs-params.yml`, but there is no information about it in the [ECS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/cmd-ecs-cli-compose.html)

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
    nginx:
        image: nginx
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on:
            - php
        volumes:
            - app:/app
            - nginx-config:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    php:
        image: ...
        restart: always
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - app:/app
            - php-config:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d

volumes:
    app:
    nginx-config:
    php-config:
```

ecs-params.yml:

```
version: 1

task_definition:
    services:
        nginx:
            cpu_shares: 256
            mem_limit: 512MB
        php:
            cpu_shares: 768
            mem_limit: 512MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Encountered the same question as you, found the answer in ecs-cli github issues:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-cli/issues/318